# RJS and Observer for Showing/Hiding a DIV

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, observer-pattern, rjs

I have an RJS template that I use to essentially do the following:

Fade out a submitted form
Show a response popup div
Bring up a new form using a partial

What I want to do is have the RJS hold off on bringing up that second form until the user has clicked the "x" button on the popup.

The RJS code so far is as follows:

```
unless @actor.health <= 0 || @actor.finished
  page.visual_effect(:fade, "act_form", :duration => 0.5)
  if @actor.acts.last.decision.consequence && @actor.acts.last.decision.consequence != ""
    page.insert_html :after, 'act_form_wrapper', :partial => 'consequence'
    page.assign 'popup', true
  end

  page.delay(1) do
    page.replace_html("act_form", :partial => 'act_form')
    if @prompt.decisions.count > 1
      page.assign 'decEmpty', true
    else
      page.assign 'decEmpty', false
    end
    if @actor.play.comment_req
      page << 'document.getElementById("act_comment").value = ""'
    end
    page.visual_effect(:appear, "act_form", :duration => 0.5)
  end

  page.replace_html("scores", :partial => 'scores')

else
  flash[:notice] = 'This game is finished. How did you do?'
  page.redirect_to(@actor)
end
```

And the popup div looks like:

```
<span class="close_consequence"><%= link_to_function image_tag('close.png', :alt => 'close'), "$('.consequence_popup').remove(); popup=false;"  %></span>
```

What I had in mind was for the "popup" Javascript variable to be used by some kind of while loop or an observer that would hold off if it was true, and then run when it was false. not sure if this is even feasible or if I should be doing this entirely differently. The RJS stuff is still quite a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make that new form hidden via inline CSS, then have have the popup dismiss also show() the new form.

```
<div id="new-form" style="display:none;">
  ...
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <div>A Popup!</div>
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).hide(); $('new-form').show();">Dismiss me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but in my case there isn't always a popup message to display when those forms get submitted, thus not always a close button to fire the show() for the new form.

Comment: In that case, I'd add a script in the page *after* the point where both the new form and popup would be rendered, which would check for existence of the popup, and show() the new form if it is not present.

Comment: Urg. This seems like it will work, but I'm using the JRails JQuery library instead of prototype, and it doesn't look like there's a way to call length on page['consequence_popup'] to check if it's there. I just get a "jQuery("#consequence_popup").length is not a function" error in Firebug.

Comment: In your original code, you reference it by className, not ID... should it instead be $('.consequence_popup'), not $('#consequence_popup') ?